# Nested Vuedraggable w/ Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuedraggable

I have this same design as an official nested vuedraggable example [here](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/functional.vue).

I am using vuex in my version and I am wondering if it is possible to update the items within  the rows with a getter/setter computed property so they trigger updating the store state. I have essentially the same file but the computed property for the getter and setter for rows updates the state, however, I can't use a getter and setter on the subcomponent (items) as I don't believe I can pass a parameter to the computed property to identify the row it resides in.

How could I do this with vuex and having an array structure of rows that have arrays of items within each row?

**UPDATE**

@HuyDuy I took your advice. I was able to use a function with an object including multiple pieces of data in it. In case someone finds this useful in the future this is how I got it to work:

```js
methods: {
      ...mapActions('builder', ['setSteps']),
    },
computed: {
        ...mapGetters('builder', ['getSteps']),
        steps: {
            get() { 
                return this.getSteps(this.stageID);
            },

            set(val) {
                this.setSteps({steps: val, stageID: this.stageID});
            }
        },
    },
```

In vuex then I have a getter like this:

```js
getSteps: (state) => (stageID) => {
        return state.stages.find(stage => stage.id === stageID).steps;
    },
```

And a setter (mutation) like this, (an action not listed here just commits it):

```js
    SETSTEPS(state, payload) {
        state.stages.find(stage => stage.id === payload.stageID).steps = payload.steps;
    },
```

This seems to sync the data, is reactive and because it's handled by a mutation I can track changes, (to provide undo and redo), which is what I was after.

Comment: You can pass parameter to computed by returning new function. And that function takes parameters.

Comment: @HuyDuy do you have an example of how you could pass parameters to both a get and set computed function that can be referenced with v-model on a component? Would these still get triggered by vuedraggable to update the state in vuex?